# Is it possible to use Page Transitions when linking to and external site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My goal is to have a login page and when the user clicks the login button, the page takes them to a web application through a different URL. However, I have been noticing that full page transitions (such as this http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/) are created with multiple divs on a page instead of linking to different pages. S

My question is, can I use page transformations when linking separated pages using CSS3 or do I need to look with different code to see if it's possible?

Comment: @Vickel They would be other pages on my server.

Answer (score 1):

When you load a new page, you lose everything from the previous page - HTML, CSS, and any scripts. So you cannot create any effects between different pages.

jQuery, GWT, and some other frameworks allow you to build applications that look as if a user is navigating from one page to another (even URLs change), but in reality a user stays on the same host page all the time. In this case you can create different transition effects.

Answer (score 1):

You could load in the external url `after` animation ?

Some Pseudo code.

```
<a href="http://www.otherdomain" class="extlink">Click to other domain</a>

<script>
   /* listen for external link clicks */
   $(".extlink").on("click", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var _href = $(this).attr("href");

     /* if the animation accepts an 'onend' callback */
     _animation.on("end", function() { window.location.href=_href; });

     /* or if css3 anim/transition, time it to the same  */
     var animTimer  = setTimeout(function() { window.location.href=_href; }, 2000);
     /* 2000 being the settings of the anim/transition in the css */

   });

</script>
```

I don't know how you are doing the page transition, but the principle would be something like this - *calling the external url after your animation.*

Comment: js here has jquery  as you have tagged

Answer (score 1):

based on your example from tympanus.net and taking in account your pages are on your server:

combine the button click for

a) doing the page transition
b) load content of the new page via ajax into one of these 'multiple divs' you mentioned